# It is possible to change MEDIA_RESOURCE_URI_DEFAULT ('public://') to just a specific subdirectory from 'public://' URI?

Tags: 7, media

I created an 'image field' with 'media file selector widget', at "Allowed URI schemes" just 'public://' and a subdirectory "article-media".

When I click to "Select media", I want to appear in my "Library" tab only pictures listed in this subdirectory ("article-media").

Is this possible?

Thank you.